# How to open Console window in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, console

I accidentally closed the Console window in Eclipse, and now I can't see the result of my code being run.

How do you open it again?

Comment: Seems to me this is something buggy in eclipse 4.  If you send the console to the "trim stack" by minimizing it and there is no current trim stack, one does not appear, and using window -> show view (the answer below) doesn't do anything.  Then there seems to be no way to get the console back...what has worked for me is minimizing the Package Explorer; then the trim appears and the Console is in it...

Answer (score 126, accepted):

From the menu bar, Window → Show View → Console. Alternately, use the keyboard shortcut:

- Mac: <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>, then <kbd>C</kbd>, or
- Windows: <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>, then <kbd>C</kbd>

[image]

Comment: In eclipse juno, after I do this, I still cannot see that elsewhere. maybe this is a bug. can you teach me how to fix this, thanks :)

Comment: ***`Shift`*** not ctrl, as proposed by an anonymous editor, I can confirm that in eclipse Kepler the shortcut is in Windows: `Alt`-`Shift`-`Q`, then `C`.

Comment: hqt: it opens in a bottom panel/pane for me in Kepler, next to 'Markers', 'Properties', etc. I only write this because first I haven't noticed it (no answer needed).

Answer (score 58):

the only solution for me was:

click on window->close all perspective (you can try also close perspective)

after this, in the top right corner click on: open perspective->resource

done

Comment: Warning: when I did this, I lost the layout of my views!

Comment: Only this worked for me in eclipse jee neon. I have tried opening console and other windows form Window-> show view But none worked. Thanks

Comment: Window->ShowView->Console did not work for me, this solution worked.

Answer (score 28):

Just open the Window(in eclipse IDE) -> click on Reset Perspective. It worked for me.

Answer (score 11):

The "trim stack" is a vertical icon bar that should appear, if it isn't there already, on one side of the main window.  Back when this answer was originally written, it was down the left hand side (of which I had a screen shot that unfortunately was uploaded to some image paste bin place and not Stack Overflow, then linked, and has since been lost).  Not being much of an eclipse user currently I don't know if this is still the case.

It contains icons for each sub-window that is minimized, so if none of them are minimized, there is no trim stack.  Try minimizing the Package Explorer/Navigator window and you should see it appear.  You can then click the "Restore" icon (the overlapping squares at the top) in the trim stack to get the window back.

BUT -- and it's not consistent -- sometimes with Eclipse Juno when the window with the Console, etc, is minimized and there is no trim stack, the trim stack doesn't appear and using "Show View" does nothing.  The way around that I've found is to minimize some other window, then the trim stack appears and the Console icon (blue & white monitor square) appears.  Click that and the Console, etc. appears in a pop-up.  Click the Restore icon in that pop-up and it will become part of the main window again.

Comment: The screen shot seems broken, maybe only me having problem can you check?

Comment: @PetterFriberg You're right.  Back when this was written I'd only been a member for less than a year and uploaded that to an "image shack" public paste site then linked it.  Obviously that copy is gone and I didn't keep one :(  So I've edited that out.  I've haven't used eclipse much in a long time, but hopefully the bug in the final paragraph has been worked out so what I'm talking about should be obvious; if not perhaps the whole design has changed, looks like there have [four major named releases since Juno](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eclipse_(software)#Releases).

Answer (score 10):

I also deleted my eclipse console by mistake, however what worked best for me was to type "console" in the "Quick Access" box to the right of the menu and that brought it right back!  I'm running version 4.2.1, not sure if this Quick Accessbox is available in other versions.

Comment: I used this method after same mistake. Awesome feature I didn't even know about, despite it staring me in the face. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Just press <kbd>Alt+Shift+Q</kbd>,<kbd>c</kbd> for quick access.(In windows)

Answer (score 2):

Window > Perspective > Reset Perspective

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Eclipse
2. Click on Window
3. Go to Show view
4. Click on Console
5. Minimize it now or drag it to the bottom and it will split between your console and other screens

Answer (score 2):

Better to save the code first, windows -> Perspective -> close all Perspective.
Then from windows -> Perspective -> open your desired perspective. Now you can all the tab which required for the perspective

Comment: Its not a good option to close all perspective, if we don't know which and all was open previously. But it worked for me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

## For C/C++ applicable

> Window -> Preferences -> C/C++ -> Build -> Console

On Limit Console output field increase a desired number of lines.

Answer (score 0):

The only reliable way to open it is Window -> Show View -> Other -> Search "console".
There was a handful suggestions in this post and none of them works! Apparently Eclipse likes to change their logic every other second.

Also, resetting the view is the most horrible suggestion, because that way you will lose everything you have ever done to change the layout, so it will probably not work for the most of the readers.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to just click on the 'Console' icon in Eclipse, like this:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

### For Java applicable

You can System.out.printf(something). And When you run the class, console will start and display.