# Accidentally closed console window in eclipse unable to enable it

Tags: eclipse

i accidentally closed console window in eclipse .In windows->show view also it is not there
please help to to enable the console window 
thanks in advance

Comment: see in the last corner of eclipse is it there.

Answer (score 0):

What eclipse version are you using? I confirmed following steps in "eclipse luna".

According to link below:

- Mac: <kbd>Option</kbd>-<kbd>Command</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>, then <kbd>C</kbd>, or
- Windows: <kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Q</kbd>, then <kbd>C</kbd>

Link:
[How to open Console window in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112670/how-to-open-console-window-in-eclipse)

Comment: I am using eclipse luna  and I already referred that link but I could not find the answer..

Comment: it is there in luna also.