# How to restore Eclipse Layout?

Tags: java, eclipse, layout

[image]

Here you can see how it looks right now.

Comment: easiest way would be to remove the current perspective and add a new one

Comment: Window->Show View
you can add those views you need.
or
Window->Reset Perspective to the default view

Comment: That is actually not working. I want to add the console, but the console is not added.

Comment: Window->Show View-> Console

Comment: And how do I add a new perspective?

Comment: @StefanBeike: Thats exactly what I did, but no reaction

Comment: I already tried to deinstall eclipse, but that didn't change anything

Answer (score 1):

From [Resetting perspectives](http://help.eclipse.org/luna/topic/org.eclipse.platform.doc.user/tasks/tasks-9j.htm):

> To restore a perspective to its original layout:
>
> - Open the  command link General > Perspectives preference page.
> - From the Available perspectives list, select the perspective you want to restore.
> - Click Reset.
> - Click OK.

Or **Window->Reset Perspective**

See [How to open Console window in Eclipse?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112670/how-to-open-console-window-in-eclipse)

Comment: I tried exactly this a several times and there are no changes.

Comment: Delete `.metadata` folder inside your workspace, Note: all the setting with this will gone. You have to import your project again.

Answer (score 1):

remove the file in the folder `$WORKSPACE_DIR/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings/`

Relaunch eclipse.

Comment: My Eclipse is broken, only your trick works for me in this topic