# console println in eclipse not printed

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, spring-data

I have made a simple spring application followin a [tutorial](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/enterprise-java/spring/spring-data-tutorial-beginners/). 
Running the application gives me no errors in the console.

**Problem:** But unfortunately I do not get any prints by the program in the console. 
I am also not able to debug because Eclipse does not stop at the break point.

**Note:** I have also found a [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4005378/console-writeline-and-system-out-println) about the eclipse console but the solutions do not really seem to work for me. I think it is a problem in my project.

**Question:** Do I have to open a special perspective to see the prinln output in the console?

Main Class:

```
public class SpringDataDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            ApplicationContext context = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("resources\\spring-configuration.xml");

            // Fetch the DAO from Spring Bean Factory
            EmployeeDao employeeDao = (EmployeeDao) context.getBean("EmployeeDaoImpl");
            Employee employee = new Employee("Employee123");
            // employee.setEmployeeId("1");

            // Save an employee Object using the configured Data source
            employeeDao.save(employee);
            System.out.println("Employee Saved with EmployeeId " + employee.getEmployeeId());

            // find an object using Primary Key
            Employee emp = employeeDao.findByPrimaryKey(employee.getEmployeeId());
            System.out.println(emp);

            // Close the ApplicationContext
            ((ConfigurableApplicationContext) context).close();
        } catch (BeansException | SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I got the Eclipse console broken once in a while too. You might have multiple threads running the same instance, just looking at the wrong console tab. 
Anyway easiest fix would be to completely restart your system.

Comment: I did a restart as you recommende. Unfortunately it did not help.

Comment: which version of java/eclipse do you use? try to update eclipse. i have just run successfully example from site with jdk jdk1.7.0_79 and eclipse version Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2) on Windows 7, Console in eclipse(menu in eclipse: Windows-> Show View->Console) contains: log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
Employee Saved with EmployeeId 2
Employee [employeeId=2, employeeName=Employee123]

Comment: if you have issue with console window please go to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112670/how-to-open-console-window-in-eclipse