# Maven command console in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven

I am using Eclipse Juno and I am wondering if there is a maven command console available in the IDE? I know in IntelliJ it has a maven console where you can write maven commands like `mvn compile` but I am not sure how to access it in eclipse?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to open Console window in Eclipse?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11112670/how-to-open-console-window-in-eclipse)

Comment: Maven console, not the system console. There is a difference.