# How to run Jenkins build job while committing via Eclipse (Windows 10)?

Tags: eclipse, git, maven, jenkins

I was experimenting with eclipse and Jenkins but something I am missing here that's why while I am committing the code to local git from eclipse Jenkins build job is not triggering. While I am adding and commit it from command line that build job is running fine. But I want the same when I am committing it from eclipse.

Can you please let me know what I need to do to make it work ?

Here what I am doing :-

1. I have a sample project where I am making the change and committing to a local git repository
2. I have created a post-commit hook script under the hook .git/hook
3. created a jenkin maven project with the details
4. making a change and code and committing it from Eclipse > Project > Team > Commit

Result: no build job started in Jenkin

Comment: What Eclipse/JGit version are you using? post-commit support is in 4.5: https://github.com/eclipse/jgit/commit/57a263f1823d164142235a72072154f0568cb61c since sept. 2016.

Comment: @VonC I am using Eclipse - Oxygen with Egit 4.6 and git 2.16 is installed in my machine

Comment: Are your sources duplicated in the Eclipse workspace, or are they referencing the local actual git repo path.

Comment: whole project is in local git repo

Comment: Is the hook executed at all when committing on Eclipse? I mean, if you add an echo at the beginning of the script, do you see it?

Comment: can you please where I will able to see if Eclipse is calling this script or not ? As I am not able to see any message in eclipse after committing, so not sure if it is calling that script or not

Comment: The eclipse console should display something (https://stackoverflow.com/q/11112670/6309)

Comment: no I can not see anything on the console. so I guess it's not calling the script. do I need to configure anything for this ? git.exe, sh.exe,bash.exe path is set in environmental variable as per https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32440968/hook-is-not-working-eclipse-egit-client but still no luck.